# How does Fabric Connect protocol work?

Tags: switch, vlan, spanning-tree

What are the algorithms that are used by Fabric Connect protocol/protocols to choose the best path to forward a packet?

I know that Fabric Connect is used to replace the Spanning Tree Protocol that chose the paths that are to be disabled in specific VLANs to prevent network loops.

Comment: You keep asking questions but never accept any answers.

Comment: @Cown I think it is a good idea to wait and maybe someone will come with more information or a more detailed answer. I always upvote useful answers, but it often happens that after someone posts a good answer, another person posts another answer with even more information.

Comment: You can always change which answer you have accepted.

Comment: @RonMaupin but then the person whose answer is initially accepted may feel bad.

Comment: Why? If a better answer comes along, then it should get the acceptance. That happens, and it is part of how SE works. I have had some of my answers accepted, then had a better answer come along and get the acceptance. I don't feel bad. The important thing is that the person asking got an acceptable answer, whether it is my answer, or an answer from someone else.

Comment: @RonMaupin I understand. However isn't it possible that an accepted question will get much much less attention from someone who has expertise in the specific field that the question is about?

Comment: Not if the person has a better answer. Having watched SE sites, especially this one, for a few years, I have noticed that people are not shy about answering questions that have accepted answers, even if the new answers are not any better than existing answers. The only real advantage to not having an accepted answer is that the question will pop up to the top in a couple of months, and it keeps popping up forever, until it gets an accepted answer. We have a problem here with that. I recently got dozens and dozens of answers, some years old, accepted by reminding people to accept an answer.

Comment: People have asked me to try to do something about all the old questions with unaccepted answers, and I did all I could, but we still have hundreds. It is simply common courtesy to reward someone who has taken the time to help you by accepting a good answer, and it keeps the site from being clogged with already answered questions.

Comment: Have you read the SPB specification? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1aq

Comment: @yoyo_fun people appreciate it when the effort they put into answering your questions gets rewarded, so it's the decent thing to do to accept answers. It seems people have started to notice you're not accepting answers, which may discourage them. So please consider accepting answers on some of the questions you've asked.